# What do you call the latter part of the afternoon when parents are scrambling to pick up children, shop, clean up and cook?

Tags: phrase-requests

What do you call the latter part of the afternoon when parents are scrambling to pick up children, shop, clean up and cook?
In Danish we call it the hour of the wolf, knowing, that it also refers to the time between night and day (3pm to 5pm).
But what's the proper wording in English?

Comment: I call it "nap time".

Comment: I don't believe I have ever heard that time specifically categorised in the UK, other than "school run time" which doesn't really convey your cited meaning very well...

Comment: I think of late afternoon as 'teatime'. After finishing school for the day, we went home for tea. Dinner or supper was served later in the evening.

Comment: I would probably call the picking-up-kids and shopping parts "rush hour", though most people wouldn't include anything they do in their own home in "rush hour".

Comment: In Denmark, "3am to 5am" is the time you collect your children from school?!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I presume the OP means that "the hour of the wolf" also means 3am to 5am as well as the late afternoon.

Comment: @Avon - I certainly hope so! But it's confusing having two terms meaning the same thing. How do they know which they are talking about?  It's like us calling the afternoon, "the early hours".

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I shudder to think of all those Danish children waiting outside the school gates until 3am. Especially if they know that that is then "the hour of the wolf".

Comment: Longfellow writes of "a pause in the day’s occupations, / That is known as the Children’s Hour." The challenge is to devise an antonym for that expression, in terms of  leisureliness, but still explicitly relevant to children.

Comment: I don't have a good answer but, if there's anywhere that it can be found (in British English) then that place is here ---> http://www.mumsnet.com/

Comment: _Rush hour_ is the norm. It doesn't need to be a big city. There are parts of the day when there are daily tasks that take place, and usually they involve travel to other locations.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, I like it -- "Children's Hour" -- No need to devise an antonym, just use it ironically (literally) or tweak it into "Brat's Hour".

Comment: I call it time for a stiff drink.

Comment: How about ***domestic** rush hour*?

Comment: In AmE there's no set phrase or word that refers to the concept you're talking about. That is, you can describe it as you did in the title and people will understand and recognize that as special, but the phrase itself isn't special.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a widely-accepted term for late afternoon but I have heard one proposed.  According to Sheldon Cooper on the US comedy show *The Big Bang Theory* ([YouTube of scene](https://youtu.be/vUflhSDbyws?t=10s)):

> **Prevening:**  "It's a time of day I invented.  It better defines the ambiguous period between afternoon and evening.  Prevening.  Fairly certain it will catch on as it fills a desperate need."

Comment: To me that evokes the Puritan concept of *prevenient* grace, *-ing* and *-ent* being both present participial endings.

Answer (score 1):

In the USA, a similar term sometimes used for the crunch times of day in the morning and late afternoon/early evening is

**[drive time](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive+time)**

> 1. The time of day during which commuters go to and from work:

This term has a strong association as a radio term though. The term **rush hour** suggested in the comments to your question (and which, I think should be an answer) may be a more general term for the same times.